# Generate random number using given number. C++

Tags: c++, random

I'm stuck with a problem. I'm making the Rock-Paper-Scissors game for my homework, but I don't know how to generate the number using just 3 specific given number and convert to character using char and ASCII
Those given numbers are :
66, 71 and 75

Comment: What do you mean by "generate random number using given number"?

Comment: I think you want `'B'`, `'G'`, `'L'` instead of magic number 66, 71, 75.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

char getRandomChar()

{
    srand(time(NULL));
    auto randomnumber = rand() % 3;
    char buf[3]={66, 71 , 75};
    return buf[randomnumber];
}
```

Comment: I think you need <time.h>, unless that's included in <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  enum Choice {ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS};

  do {
      printf("Please enter your choice: ");
      char yours; //your choice
      scanf(" %c",&yours);

      if (yours=='q'){
          break;
      }

      Choice computers = static_cast<Choice>( rand() % 3 );

      if ((yours=='r' && computers==ROCK)||
          (yours=='p' && computers==PAPER)||
          (yours=='s' && computers==SCISSORS))
      {
          printf("Its a draw.\n\n");
          continue;
      }

      if ((yours=='r' && computers==SCISSORS)||
          (yours=='p' && computers==ROCK)||
          (yours=='s' && computers==PAPER))
      {
          printf("Congratulations, you won!\n\n");
      } else {
          printf("Sorry, you loose :-( \n\n");
      }

  } while(true);

  return 0;
}
```

There exists a hacky solution using the fact that characters `r`, `p`, `s` are close in the ASCII table. The position of `p` in ASCII is 112. You could count rand()%4+112 and compare that with your char converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

This code will choose one of your three numbers, in this case it outputs them to the output stream...

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0)); // ensure truly randomized number   

    int nums[3] = {66, 71, 75};
    int i = rand() % 3; // find random number between 0 and 2

    cout << nums[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"ensure truly randomized number"* sorry to nick pick, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using the ASCII numbers. It will save you some lines of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf, scanf, puts, NULL */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

int main ()
{
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  enum Choice {PAPER=112, QUIT, ROCK, SCISSORS};

  do {
      printf("Please enter your choice (r/p/s; q to quit): ");
      char yours; //your choice
      scanf(" %c",&yours);

      if (yours=='q'){
          break;
      }

      Choice computers;
      do {
        computers = static_cast<Choice>( 112 + rand() % 4  );
      } while (computers==QUIT);

      if (yours==computers)
      {
          printf("Its a draw.\n\n");
          continue;
      }

      if ((yours=='r' && computers==SCISSORS)||
          (yours=='p' && computers==ROCK)||
          (yours=='s' && computers==PAPER))
      {
          printf("Congratulations, you won!\n\n");
      } else {
          printf("Sorry, you loose :-( \n\n");
      }

  } while(true);

  return 0;
}
```